# Creating Alarm in AWS for EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, alarm

How to create alarm when
1) Alert when EC2 instance runs for too long (Say for 1 hour).
2)Alert when number of EC2 instances reaches a threshold (say 5 instances at a time)

One more assumption is, these EC2 instance are specific.Say these alerts applicable to EC2 instances where their instance name start with "test".

When i try to create the alarm , i  haven't see this logic in Metrics. Standard Metrics include CPU Utilization, Network In, Network Out etc.

Is there a way to create this alarm either by defining our custom metrics or some other options?

Comment: Have you explored cloudwatch documentation? Their are apis which allow you to publish metrics

Comment: @Shibashis had a look into publich metrics.But i am not sure where the logics of the metrics is defined.Eg: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-data.html , i am seing only metric name, statiscal outputs  and  units are defined. But what i want is, suppose metric name is EC2InstanceHealthDuration (means how long the EC2 instances ran until it started).There should be some unix scripts about the logic that metric name is doing. Please let me know where can i find the same.

Comment: cloudwatch only collects stats and allows you to create alerts on them, You will need to create scripts for watching how long the instance has been up and then push that metric to cloudwatch. If you dont want to develop such logic you may need to consider other software like datadog,new relic, nagios etc

Comment: Thanks @Shibashis, so as for the above requirement 1) when EC2 instance runs for too long (Say for 1 hour). 2)Alert when number of EC2 instances reaches a threshold(say 5 instances at a time) doesn't able to use standard metrics. If we write a custom metric, where we have to write the logic of the scripts. I saw in  put-metric-data (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-data.html), there is no option to place the scripts. It would be good, if you throw some light on this.

Comment: For pushing the metric u have many options, i would suggest one of these three options 1> place the scripts on instance themselves 2> create another ec2 where the scripts will run 3> Use AWS lambda scheduled events to push the metrics.

Comment: Aws lambda would be my preferred option, if i cant for some reason add metrics from the instance itself

Comment: Shibashis solution its not a propper solution for example when xmrig malware alterate your lambdas. In that case your are not detecting when the malware is creating new isntances. Check this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48226818/4398385

Answer (score 2):

For automatically deployed instances it’s impossible to setup CloudWatch Alarm as you do not know the instance ID. 
The only way to setup an alarm was to create an AWS Lambda function that poles all the running instances and compares their launch time to a specified timeout.

The lambda function is periodically triggered by a [CloudWatch - Event – Rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html).

Use [tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) to specify different run durations to different machines. For example your launch tool should tag the instance with key value “Test”

Please note this code comes with **NO** warranties at all! This is more of an example.

```
import boto3
import datetime
import json
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

INSTANCE_TIMEOUT = 24
MAX_PERMITTED_INSTANCES = 5 
MAILING_LIST = "jon.doh@simpsons.duf, drunk@beer.com"

def parse_tag(tags, keyValuePair):
    for tag in tags:
        if tag['Key'] == keyValuePair[0] and tag['Value'] == keyValuePair[1]:
            return True
    return False

def runtimeExceeded(instance, timeOutHours):
    # Working in to UTC to avoid time-travel during daylight-saving changeover
    timeNow = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    instanceRuntime = timeNow - instance.launch_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
    print instanceRuntime
    if instanceRuntime > datetime.timedelta(hours=timeOutHours):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def sendAlert(instance, message):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'AWS_Notification@sourcevertex.net'
    msg['To'] = MAILING_LIST
    msg['Subject'] = "AWS Alert: " + message
    bodyText = '\n\nThis message was sent by the AWS Monitor ' + \
        'Lambda. For details see AwsConsole-Lambdas. \n\nIf you want to ' + \
        'exclude an instance from this monitor, tag it ' + \
        'with Key=RuntimeMonitor Value=False'

    messageBody = MIMEText( message + '\nInstance ID: ' +
                    str(instance.instance_id) + '\nIn Availability zone: '
                    + str(instance.placement['AvailabilityZone']) + bodyText)
    msg.attach(messageBody)

    ses = boto3.client('ses')
    ses.send_raw_email(RawMessage={'Data' : msg.as_string()})

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    aws_regions = ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']
    for region in aws_regions:
        runningInstancesCount = 0
        try:
            ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region['RegionName'])
            ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2',
                            region_name=region['RegionName'])
            aws_region = region['RegionName']

            instances = ec2_resource.instances.all()

            for i in instances:
                if i.state['Name'] == 'running':
                    runningInstancesCount +=1
                    if i.tags != None:
                        if parse_tag(i.tags, ('RuntimeMonitor', 'False')):
                            # Ignore these instances
                            pass
                        else:
                            if runtimeExceeded(i, INSTANCE_TIMEOUT):
                                sendAlert(i, "An EC2 instance has been running " + \
                                "for over {0} hours".format(INSTANCE_TIMEOUT))
                    else:
                        print "Untagged instence"
                        if runtimeExceeded(i, UNKNOWN_INSTANCE_TIMEOUT):
                                sendAlert(i, "An EC2 instance has been running " + \
                                "for over {0} hours".format(UNKNOWN_INSTANCE_TIMEOUT))

        except Exception as e:
            print e
            continue

        if runningInstancesCount > MAX_PERMITTED_INSTANCES:
            sendAlert(i, "Number of running instances exceeded threshold  " + \
                    "{0} running instances".format(runningInstancesCount))

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Metric to publish the events in CloudWatch and then you can use that event to set an alarm.