# SNS notification for ec2 instance creation and termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I would like to get notified via email, whenever an ec2 instance is created/terminated in my AWS account. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest method (IMO) to do that is to use CloudWatch Events service along with an SNS topic configured to send out emails to your email ID.

In AWS web console, go to CloudWatch -> Events (On left panel) -> Rules -> 'Create rule'

In 'Event Source' choose 'Event Pattern'. Then choose 'Events By Service'. In front of 'Service Name' select 'EC2' and for 'Event Type', select 'EC2 Instance State-change Notification'. You can either choose 'Any State' to get a notification on every state-change or choose specific state you are interested in ('Running' and 'Terminated'|'Stopped' might be of your interest). On the right, Click 'Add target' and then choose 'SNS topic' from dropdown. Then choose an SNS topic that you have configured already to send notification emails to your email ID.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: But doing this doesn't notify me when a ec2 instance is launched. Is there any way I can get notified when a new instance is launched?

Comment: @VineethVenugopal as mentioned by "helloV", you will have to watch for "RunInstances" event for monitoring instance creation and "TerminateInstances" for monitoring instance termination.

Comment: @VineethVenugopal this will notify you every time any instance changes state, including new instances as they transition to pending and then to running.

Comment: If you're only interested in notifications when an instance is created or terminated, as indicated by OP, then you can configure the event rule to target the "Pending" and "Terminated" states, respectively. This avoids extraneous notifications, such as for reboots. See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways to solve this:

1. Enable **Cloudtrail** and stream it to **Cloudwatch**. In Cloudwatch you create rules to send an SNS when an instance is created. There'll be some charges for Cloudtrail and Cloudwatch.
2. Use **Lambda**: When CloudTrail creates an object in S3, trigger an event that causes a Lambda function to execute. The Lambda function then parses the S3 object and check for `RunInstances` event. If it finds `RunInstances`, extracts other attributes of the instance and use AWS SES to send a mail.

**Solution 1**: AWS handles everything. Incurs a tiny AWS charge (Cloudwatch + SNS). Not much opportunity to know how things work.

**Solution 2**: From Cloudtrail onwards, you control the flow. Lambda and SES are practically free (Lambda executions are free up to certain limit, up to 200 emails are free in SES sandbox mode). Opportunity to learn about S3/Lambda/SES.

Comment: the problem is that this that cloudtrail does not deliver the messages instantly!!